# How can I soft wrap the gundo preview?

Tags: wrapping

As the title. Basically I want to apply `set linebreak` to the `gundo` window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
augroup MyGundo
    au!
    au BufWinEnter __Gundo_Preview__ :setl linebreak wrap
augroup end
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I just failed in finding the name of the buffer:-)

Answer (score 1):

Before you get better answer, you can go to `/autoload/gundo.vim` (or wherever it is), there should be two functions `GundoSettingsGraph()` and `GundoSettingsPreview()` (depends on which you desire to change), and there you can change `setlocal nowrap` to `setlocal wrap`.